# Using Gulp to build Javascript, inconsistent "typeof" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, gulp, typeof

I am having a very odd error occur when I am trying to build a full .js file for my small webapp.  Everytime I attempt to run the app, I get an error in Chrome Developer Tools stating:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error occurs in various files and at seemingly random points of code, with the same gulp build! It even occurs with well known libs such as Foundation, moment.js, etc... Sometimes at the end of a file, sometimes right in the middle, such as this one from the html5-boilerplate plugins.js:

[image]

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

var paths = {
    alljs: [
        'src/main/webapp/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'src/main/webapp/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        'src/main/webapp/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/main.js',
        'src/main/webapp/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/plugins.js',        
        'src/main/webapp/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.js',
        'src/main/webapp/bower_components/moment/moment.js',
        'src/main/webapp/js/libs/*.js',
        'src/main/webapp/js/core/*.js',
        'src/main/webapp/js/init-and-load.js'
    ]
};


gulp.task('alljs', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.alljs)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify({preserveComments:'some'}))      
    .pipe(concat('build-all.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../sourcemaps/all'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/main/webapp/public/js/'))
    .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

The only thing that I can think of is that gulp is concat'ing the files incorrectly, as I was having trouble preserving comments when I did the concat section of the pipe before the uglify section.  Thanks for the help.